# FQL - How do i filter friends based on their work history

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am trying to filter my friends based on work history by using fql, but fql does not return any results.
Here is the fql i am trying:
select uid,username,work from user where uid in (select uid1 from friend where uid2 = $myid) and work.employer.id IN ($someid)

i get the result - 
{
  "data": [
  ]
}

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the work field doesn't obey like the other fields due to how the arrays are set up for each each work object. For example `strlen(work.employer.id)` gives 0.

So in short FQL doesn't support this feature. You can try submitting a bug report.